# Visual studio 2010 intellisense methods order

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm writing in C++. Visual Studio 2010 intellisense shows methods in alphabetical order. 
Is there a way to make it show methods in original order (the order they appear in source code)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the order of constructors listed in IntelliSense in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391332/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-order-of-constructors-listed-in-intellisense-in-vis)

Answer (score 2):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391332/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-order-of-constructors-listed-in-intellisense-in-vis)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391360/873644):

> There isn't a way to control the ordering within Visual Studio's Intellisense. If you do have multiple constructors (or methods), your only real control in terms of intellisense is to use EditorBrowsable with the appropriate EditorBrowsableState. This allows you to hide a contructor (or method) in intellisense, or only have it displayed in "advanced" mode, but does not allow you to reorder them.