# Why EditorBrowsableState attribute not working with default constructors?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

Why EditorBrowsableState attribute not working with default constructors?
while working with properties?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What happens to make you think it's *not working?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to change the order of constructors listed in IntelliSense in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391332/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-order-of-constructors-listed-in-intellisense-in-vis)