# Is it poor design to have a class used only by one other class?

Tags: oop

I have a `QueueProcessor` class that processes a work queue. I want to send an email out of a summary of all work done with a bunch of statistics. I am already using a mail class (`Zend_Mail`), so most of the email work is abstracted away for me, but I still have to figure out where to put the code to generate the summary information. I'm basically collecting data during the processing and then I have to transform the data into a format suitable for email.

My question is, should I create a separate class called `QueueProcessorSummaryEmail`, or is that considered bad design since it's extremely tightly coupled to the original class? If I *did* make it it's own class, I'd have to pass a ton of data to it for it to generate the email, but it'd be nice to have that kind of separation. If I *don't* make it a class, all the data is available from inside the `QueueProcessor` class, but it just feels weird mixing the processing logic and the reporting generating logic in one class.

And for the record, when I say "report generating logic", I don't mean I'm generating HTML inline; I'm using a view for that. By formatting I mean taking the data and aggregating it into something usable by the email report.

Comment: Why not making QueueProcessorSummaryEmail as inner Class of QueueProcessor? So you dont need to pass any data.

Comment: In C# StyleCop will complain about more than one class per file. anyhow, if it works and is relatively bug-free, why not move on to other bugs and features? Thinking too much about patterns and class hierarchy (the high-level stuff) can keep you from being agile. The most important changes to your code will come from real-life clients complaining that they need feature A) and that they cannot stand bug B) - things that you do not yet know about. So, get it done, get it out there, and then, after it is mature, polish it.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan Don't get too attached to being agile. Agile has its place and has advantages, but there is such a thing as technical debt. Don't let the current buzz i.e. Agile, Sigma Six or whatever other management style is currently in vogue get completely in the way of good judgment.

Comment: @Hamish - Agile has to be tempered with some design and forethought.  Otherwise, when clients complain that they need feature A and can't stand bug B, you have to totally re-architect what you've done, potentially wasting any time you saved by being agile.  Agile is a good thing, but it's not a silver bullet.

Comment: Ok, ok, but let's not put 6sigma and "agile" in the same category. 6sigma might apply to repetitive tasks like typing, but programming is a tad more than that (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ryeguy,

My suggestion would be to create a decorator class (like say SummarizedQueryProcessor) to extend the functionality of the QueueProcessor.  This will allow for a higher degree of separation of concerns and will simplify unit testing.

Ted

Answer (score 4):

> is that considered bad design since it's extremely tightly coupled to the original class?

No, that's not a problem.  Subclass-superclass design is also tightly coupled.

> it just feels weird mixing the processing logic and the reporting generating logic in one class.

Delegation of reporting/summary often makes sense.  Reporting changes and expands more quickly than the processing does.

Answer (score 1):

One way to help de-couple your design is by using **interfaces**.  For example, you could create an interface called `ISummaryDataProvider` and have `QueueProcessor` implement that interface with the properties and methods that would be needed to provide the data for another class that handles the summary data.

Then, you can have your constructor for `QueueProcessorSummaryEmail` take in an `ISummaryDataProvider` as a parameter.  That way, if you ever decide to get your summary data from something other than `QueueProcessor`, you just need to make sure that your new data source implements `ISummaryDataProvider` so that it can be properly consumed by `QueueProcessorSummaryEmail`.

---

I explored similar object-oriented-design questions in my question [How should I model my code to maximize code re-use in this specific situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389588/how-should-i-model-my-code-to-maximize-code-re-use-in-this-specific-situation).  One of the answers suggested using **Dependency Injection**, which I didn't really understand before.  You can see at the bottom of my question how I implemented this solution in a loosely-coupled way.  You may find the information there helpful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

ryeguy,

i'd be tempted to make the `QueueProcessor` class the base abstract class and then Extend that to create the `QueueProcessorSummaryMail` class.

ok, basic example:

```
class QueueProcessor
{
     // all your methods and properties
}

class QueueProcessorSummaryMail extends QueueProcessor
{
     // add your custom properties and methods here
}
```

Hopefully, this gives you the main idea.

jim

[edit] that of course is for php. for c#, you'd still use either abstract classes or an interface.

Comment: I don't think that's a good use of inheritance, it's not an "is-a" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Structure matters. If there is a set of logic that doesn't really belong in a class then refactoring it elsewhere can really help mainatainability in the future.

In a languages that support inner classes you could just make it an inner class. May be later you separate it and reuse it and then need to pass data to it at that point you might define an Interface that the  Mail class accepts, and which Queue Processor implements.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
public interface WorkProcessorI {
    public void process( WorkQueue queue ); // could also be something like "process( Task[] queue )"
}

public interface SummaryGeneratorI () {
    public String[][] generateSummary(); // returns subscripted string array of name/values or whatever
}

public class QueueProcessor implements WorkProcessorI, SummaryGeneratorI {
    public void process( WorkQueue queue ) {
        // process queue populating member values that will be used to generate the summary.
     }

     public String[][] generateSummary() {
        // read values that were populated by the process( WorkQueue ) method.
     }
}

public class SummaryMail {
    private String[][] summary = null;
    public void setSummary( String[][] argSummary ) {
        this.summary = argSummary;
    }
    // to, from, server, cc, bcc, subject, Additional body text, ...

    public void send() {
        // sends email via whatever api you want.
    }
}
```