# Why can't I change the scope of my object with ServiceStacks IoC?

Tags: servicestack

Given the following code from my Configure method:

```
OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("Oracle:FEConnection"), OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory)).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request); // <== this does NOT work

// But these work
container.Register<IPreprocessorRepository>(c => new CachedPreprocessorRepository(dbFactory, c.Resolve<ICacheClient>())).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Default);
container.Register<IPreprocessor>(c => new DirectApiPreprocessor(c.Resolve<IPreprocessorRepository>(), c.Resolve<IValidator<LeadInformation>>())).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Default);
```

How can I make sure that the dbFactory instanciated is used in other registrations will per request?

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Please fix your title.

Comment: Thanks Mike, totally brain farted that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the scope of this:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory)
    .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

Because you're only passing in an **instance** of an object, and not a **factory function** that the IOC would need to be able to instantiate instances of the object itself. All the IOC can do in this case is return the instance, making it a singleton.

To be able to change the scope you would need to register a delegate that can create an instance, i.e:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => 
      new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(...))
    .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

But you never want to do this with any connection or client factories like `IDbConnectionFactory` or `IRedisClientsManager` since they're designed to be used as singletons.

i.e. They're thread-safe singleton factories used to create single client/connection instances:

```
using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    //...
}

using (var redis = container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: @StephenPatten ok I've added the approach I would take: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26796083/85785