# Custom Authentication using connection string based on user is creating incorrect IDbConnectionFactory

Tags: servicestack

This issue has recently cropped up in our production environment as more users are beginning to use our webservice.  My goal with authentication for this service was to have a list of web service users in our database that each had access to a separate database (and by extension a separate connection string).

We have a layout like this:
MasterDB
Customer1DB
Customer2DB
Customer3DB
etc..

In the MasterDB we have all the users stored for access to the webservice in addition to the connection string they would need to use.  What I am experiencing (and I have figured it out through logging) is that Customer1 will log in, the correct connection string will be used when creating the dbFactory, but when using the dbFactory in my service class it will be using a previous user's database.

I am not really sure how to approach the problem, as I am pretty inexperienced with ServiceStack.  Below is my Global.asax, my CustomAuthUserSession class, and a sample service that is seeing this problem:

**Global.asax in Configure**

```
private void HandleAuthentication(Funq.Container container)
{
    var userRepo = GetUserRepository(container);
    CreateUserAuthentications(userRepo);
}

private InMemoryAuthRepository GetUserRepository(Funq.Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
        () => new CustomAuthUserSession(container),
        new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider(), }));

    var userRepo = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepo);
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

    return userRepo;
}

private void CreateUserAuthentications(InMemoryAuthRepository userRepo)
{
    IDbConnectionFactory dbFactoryMaster = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
        "Data Source=www.oursite.com;Initial Catalog=Master;User=User;Password=asdf1234;enlist=false;",
        SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

    using (IDbConnection db = dbFactoryMaster.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        try 
        {
            var users = db.Select<tbl_WebServiceUsers>();

            foreach (tbl_WebServiceUsers user in users)
            {
                tbl_Instances instance = db.Select<tbl_Instances>(u => u.InstanceID == user.InstanceID)[0];
                string hash;
                string salt;

                new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString(user.Password, out hash, out salt);
                userRepo.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
                {
                    Id = user.ServiceUserID,
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    PasswordHash = hash,
                    Salt = salt,
                    RefIdStr = instance.InstanceConnectionString
                }, user.Password);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthUserSession.cs**

```
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Auth;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.Logging;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GrowerLiveAPI.App
{
    public class CustomAuthUserSession : AuthUserSession
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public Funq.Container container;

        public CustomAuthUserSession(Funq.Container container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
            var service = authService.ResolveService<IUserAuthRepository>();
            var userAuth = service.GetUserAuth(session, tokens);
            ConnectionString = userAuth.RefIdStr;

            authService.SaveSession(this, SessionFeature.DefaultSessionExpiry);

            var log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
            log.Info("Authenticated to webservice using: {0}".Fmt(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(session.UserAuthName)));

            HandleConnection();
        }

        private void HandleConnection()
        {
            ModifyConnectionString();

            var log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
            log.Info("Connected to database using: {0}".Fmt(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(ConnectionString)));

            var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConnectionString, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
        }

        private void ModifyConnectionString()
        {
            string mode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevelopmentMode"].ToUpper();

            if (mode == "DEVELOPMENT")
            {
                ConnectionString = ConnectionString.Replace("localaddress", "remoteaddress");
            }
            else if (mode == "STAGING")
            {
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StagingConnectionString"];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Some code from a sample service**

```
public class tbl_OrdersDataRepo
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory { get; set; }

    public object PostOrder(tbl_Orders order)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsInsertRequest(order))
                {
                    return InsertOrder(db, order);
                }
                else
                {
                    return UpdateOrder(db, order);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private Boolean IsInsertRequest(tbl_Orders order)
    {
        if (order.OrderID > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private int InsertOrder(IDbConnection db, tbl_Orders order)
    {
        if (order.OrderExternalID > 0)
        {
            tbl_Orders orderWithMappedIDs = mapExternalIDsToInternalIDs(db, order);
            return (int)db.Insert(orderWithMappedIDs, selectIdentity: true);
        }
        else
        {
            return (int)db.Insert(order, selectIdentity: true);
        }
    }

    private int UpdateOrder(IDbConnection db, tbl_Orders order)
    {
        tbl_Orders updatedOrder;

        if (order.OrderExternalID > 0)
        {
            tbl_Orders orderWithMappedIDs = mapExternalIDsToInternalIDs(db, order);
            tbl_Orders internalOrder = getOrder(db, orderWithMappedIDs.OrderID);
            updatedOrder = getUpdatedOrder(internalOrder, orderWithMappedIDs);
        }
        else
        {
            tbl_Orders internalOrder = getOrder(db, order.OrderID);
            updatedOrder = getUpdatedOrder(internalOrder, order);
        }

        db.Update(updatedOrder);
        return updatedOrder.OrderID;
    }

    private tbl_Orders mapExternalIDsToInternalIDs(IDbConnection db, tbl_Orders externalOrder)
    {
        tbl_Orders internalOrder = externalOrder;

        if (externalOrder.CustomerLocationID > 0)
            internalOrder.CustomerLocationID = getInternalCustomerLocationID(db, externalOrder.CustomerLocationID);

        if (externalOrder.NurseryLocationID > 0)
            internalOrder.NurseryLocationID = getInternalNurseryLocationID(db, externalOrder.NurseryLocationID);

        if (externalOrder.UserID > 0)
            internalOrder.UserID = getInternalUserID(db, "harmony");

        if (externalOrder.OrderTypeID > 0)
            internalOrder.OrderTypeID = getInternalOrderTypeID(db, externalOrder.OrderTypeID);

        if (externalOrder.EDIStatusID > 0)
            internalOrder.EDIStatusID = getInternalEDIStatusID(db, externalOrder.EDIStatusID);

        if (externalOrder.OrderDeliveryTimeWindowID > 0)
            internalOrder.OrderDeliveryTimeWindowID = getInternalOrderDeliveryTimeWindowID(db, externalOrder.OrderDeliveryTimeWindowID);

        return internalOrder;
    }

    private int getInternalCustomerLocationID(IDbConnection db, int externalCustomerLocationID)
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
        log.Info("Searching for an ExternalCustomerLocationID: {0}".Fmt(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(externalCustomerLocationID)));
        log.Info("In the database: {0}".Fmt(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(db.Database)));

        List<tbl_CustomerLocations> internalCustomers = db.Select<tbl_CustomerLocations>(c => c.CustomerLocationExternalID == externalCustomerLocationID);
        if (internalCustomers.Count > 0)
        {
            tbl_CustomerLocations internalCustomer = internalCustomers[0];
            return internalCustomer.CustomerLocationID;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot find a customer location with an id of '" + externalCustomerLocationID + "' in the remote database.  " +
                "Please make sure that the customer location exists in both databases, and that its external id is equal to " + externalCustomerLocationID + ".");
        }
    }
```

Sorry about the length of this post, but I figured too much information is better than too little.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's IOC and Host Configuration should be configured within `AppHost.Configure()` and remain immutable there after, i.e IOC dependencies should never be modified at runtime.

If you're storing the Customers Connection Strings in the session than you can you can open a connection for the users specific database, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
     public object Any(Request request)
     {
         var session = base.SessionAs<CustomAuthUserSession>();

         using (var db = TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()
             .OpenDbConnectionString(session.ConnectionString))
         {
             //..
         }
     }
}
```

An alternative is to store Connection Strings in the [RequestContext and use a custom IDbConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796083/85785).