# Access ServiceStack session from ConnectionFilter

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using SQL Server and database triggers to keep a data-level audit of all changes to the system.  This audit includes the userID / name of whomever initiated a change.  Ideally I'd like to do something like this in my `AppHost.Configure` method:

```
SqlServerDialect.Provider.UseUnicode = true;
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider)
        {
            ConnectionFilter = (db =>
            {
                IAuthSession session = this.Request.GetSession();
                if (session != null && !session.UserName.IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "declare @ci varbinary(128); select @ci = CAST(@Username as varbinary(128)); set context_info @ci";
                    System.Data.IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                    param.ParameterName = "Username";
                    param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
                    //param.Value = session.UserName;
                    param.Value = session.UserAuthId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                return new ProfiledDbConnection(db, Profiler.Current);
            }),
            AutoDisposeConnection = true
        };
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
```

Of course, this doesn't work because `this.Request` doesn't exist.  Is there any way to access the current session from the ConnectionFilter or ExecFilter on an OrmLite connection?

The other approach I had started, doing an override of the `Db` property of `Service`, doesn't work any more because I've abstracted some activities into their own interfaced implementations to allow for mocks during testing.  Each of these is passed a function that is expected to return the a DB connection.  Example:

```
// Transaction processor
container.Register<ITransactionProcessor>(new MockTransactionProcessor(() => dbFactory.OpenDbConnection()));
```

So, how can I ensure that any DML executed has the (admittedly database-specific) context information needed for my database audit triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earlier [multi tenant ServiceStack example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796083/85785) shows how you can use the Request Context to store per-request items, e.g. you can populate the Request Context from a Global Request filter:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    var session = req.GetSession();
    if (session != null)
        RequestContext.Instance.Items.Add(
            "UserName", session.UserName);
});
```

And access it within your Connection Filter:

```
ConnectionFilter = (db =>
{
    var userName = RequestContext.Instance.Items["UserName"] as string;
    if (!userName.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
       //...
    }
}),
```

Comment: I saw `RequestContext` and it sparked something, but it was empty in debugging.  I of course didn't think of populating it!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a factory pattern, similar to how ServiceStack creates OrmLite db connections in the first place.  Since all user-associated calls are made via the ServiceRunner, I piggy-back off of the session that's managed by ServiceStack.

```
public class TransactionProcessorFactory : ITransactionProcessorFactory
{
    public ITransactionProcessor CreateTransactionProcessor(IDbConnection Db)
    {
        return new TransactionProcessor(Db);
    }
}

public abstract MyBaseService : Service
{
    private IDbConnection db;

    public override System.Data.IDbConnection Db
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.db != null) return db;

            this.db = this.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection();

            IAuthSession session = this.Request.GetSession();

            if (session != null && !session.UserName.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                IDbCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "declare @ci varbinary(128); select @ci = CAST(@Username as varbinary(128)); set context_info @ci";
                IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "Username";
                param.DbType = DbType.String;
                //param.Value = session.UserName;
                param.Value = session.UserAuthId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }

    private ITransactionProcessor tp = null;
    public virtual ITransactionProcessor TransactionProcessor
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.tp != null) return tp;
            var factory = this.TryResolve<ITransactionProcessorFactory>();
            this.tp = factory.CreateTransactionProcessor(this.Db);

            return tp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I prefer this approach instead :)

Comment: Not good. What if you need to implement `Db` property in your repository -- you will need repositories the moment your service starts fleshing out. Wrap the whole db connection context initialization in a custom db factory and use DI to auto-wire a public `IDbConnectionFactory` property so you can reuse it in your repos later.

Comment: So, basically a `IDbConnectionFactoryFactory`?

Comment: @jklemmack: Wat? I meant a `public class MySqlServerFactory : IDbConnectionFactory` implementation which gets injected.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of potential future ServiceStack users, another approach would be to use OrmLite's [Global Insert/Update filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#global-insert--update-filters) combined with [Mythz's approach above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222185/508681) to inject the necessary SQL only when DML actions are made.  It isn't 100%, since there may be stored procs or manual SQL, but that's potentially handled via an `IDbConnection` extension method to manually set desired auditing information.