# Are there any advantages of Property Injection over Constructor Injection?

Tags: .net, code-injection, constructor-injection, property-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dependency injection through constructors or property setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503584/dependency-injection-through-constructors-or-property-setters)

I'm curios if **Property Injection** has any advantages over **Constructor Injection**:

```
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {
    [Inject]
    public ICookiesManager CookiesManager {get; set;}

    [Inject]
    public ISecurityManager SecurityManager {get; set;}

    public LoginController()
    {

    }
  }
```

vs

```
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {
    private ICookiesManager _cookiesManager;
    private ISecurityManager _securityManager;

    public LoginController(ICookiesManager cookiesManager, ISecurityManager securityManager)
    {
      _securityManager = securityManager;
      _cookiesManager = cookiesManager;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's very little effective difference in the two patterns other than with property injection, you can replace the implementation with a simple property set. With constructor injection, it's more explicit (usually) that you don't want anyone to replace the implementation at runtime (as doing so would require creating a new LoginController.)

Comment: Yes, property injection allows replacing of logic in already created objects, but this can be a disadvantage of Property Injection at the same time. I'm looking for advantages :)