# Android IOC Dagger Framework - How to inject a nested field ?

Tags: android, inversion-of-control, dagger

I'm using Dagger for Android for dependency injections.
I have a UserService object in a Main Class:

```
public class Main implements Runnable {

@Inject
UserService service;

@Override
public void run() {
    for (User f : service.getUserByName("toto")) {
        System.out.print(f.getM_Nom());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new UserModule());
    Main m = objectGraph.get(Main.class);
    m.run();
}
}
```

I managed to inject the "service" field and to call the method "getUserByName("")". 
But in my "UserService", I have an other custom object ("RepositoryUser" class):

```
public class UserService implements IUserService {

@Inject
RepositoryUser m_Repository;


@Override
public List<User> getUserByName(String name) {
    return m_Repository.getAll();
}
}
```

My problem is that this field is not inject: the "m_Repository" field is null and I get a null pointer exception when I try to use my RepositoryUser object.

Here is my Provider:

```
@Module(
    injects = {UserService.class, Main.class, RepositoryUser.class}
)
 public class UserModule {

@Provides
RepositoryUser provideRepositoryUser() {
    return new RepositoryUser();
}

@Provides
UserService provideUserService() {
    return new UserService();
}
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is preferrable to use [Constructor Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503584/dependency-injection-through-constructors-or-property-setters) in this case. This can be achieved as follows:

**Main**:

```
public class Main implements Runnable {

    private final IUserService service;

    @Inject
    public Main(IUserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (User f : service.getUserByName("toto")) {
            System.out.print(f.getM_Nom());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new UserModule());
        Main m = objectGraph.get(Main.class);
        m.run();
    }
}
```

**UserService**:

```
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    private final RepositoryUser m_Repository;

    @Inject
    public UserService(RepositoryUser repository) {
        m_Repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserByName(String name) {
        return m_Repository.getAll();
    }
}
```

**RepositoryUser**:

```
public class RepositoryUser {

    @Inject
    public RepositoryUser() {
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**UserModule**:

```
@Module(injects = Main.class)
public class UserModule {

    @Provides
    IUserService provideIUserService(UserService userService){
        return userService;
    }
}
```

Everywhere the `@Inject` annotation is present on a constructor, Dagger can automatically create an instance of that item. So when you request a `RepositoryUser` instance in the `UserService` constructor, Dagger will see the `@Inject` annotation on `RepositoryUser`'s constructor, and use that to create a new instance. We do not need an `@Provides` method here.

The `IUserService` parameter on the `Main` constructor cannot be instantiated, since it is an interface. Using the `provideIUserService` method in the module, we tell Dagger that we want it to create a new `UserService` instance.

We do have an `@Inject` annotation on the `Main` constructor, but we request it using `ObjectGraph.get(Class<T> clzz)`. Therefore, we need to add `injects = Main.class` to our module.

Comment: And what about unit testing and Mock objects ? How can I inject a mock repository to test my Service so ?

Comment: Don't use Dagger :). `RepositoryUser repository = mock(RepositoryUser.class); UserService service = new UserService(repository);`