# Trouble Grapsing Dagger Fundamentals

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am attempting to use Dagger as my Android app's dependency injection library. In my project, I have different Android modules in the project representing different flavors of the app. I want to use dependency injection to allow each module to define its own navigation menu.

My MenuFragment class requires an instance of my interface (MenuAdapterGenerator):

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject
    protected MenuAdapterGenerator generator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        //this.generator is always null here, though shouldn't it be injected already?:
        BaseExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(inflater, this.generator);
    }
}
```

This is what my menu module looks like:

```
@Module (
    injects = MenuAdapterGenerator.class
)
public class MenuDaggerModule {
    public MenuDaggerModule() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Provides @Singleton MenuAdapterGenerator provideMenuAdapterGenerator() {
        return new MenuNavAdapterGenerator();
    }

}
```

Here is the overall app-level module (which includes this MenuDaggerModule):

```
@Module (
    includes = MenuDaggerModule.class,
    complete = true
)
public class OverallAppModule {

}
```

(Edit:) Here is my MainActivity class which creates the object graph:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ObjectGraph objGraph;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.objGraph = ObjectGraph.create(OverallAppModule.class);
    this.mainWrapper = new MainWrapper(this, this.objGraph);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Other instantiation logic
}
```

(Edit:) And here is where I actually make my MenuFragment (in MainWrapper):

```
public class MainWrapper {

    public MainWrapper(Activity activity, ObjectGraph objGraph) {
        this.menu = new MenuFragment();
        this.objGraph.inject(this.menu);
        //I have no idea what the above line really does
        FragmentManager fm = this.activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_fragment, this.menu);
        t.commit();
    }

}
```

Why is my module's provideMenuAdapterGenerator method not called to inject my MenuAdapterGenerator? If I set a breakpoint in that method, it is never tripped. But the MenuDaggerModule is getting created, because System.out.println("test"); is being hit.

My understanding is that if the MenuDaggerModule is created (which it is), Dagger should then use that provideMenuAdapterGenerator() anytime a @Injects MenuAdapterGenerator is encountered. What do I have wrong?

Comment: Can you show where and how you create your `ObjectGraph` and do your dependency injection?

Comment: @NiekHaarman Edited and added it as the last section of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger is a lot of magic, but not *that* much. You still need to tell Dagger to inject your instances.

I will assume you've got a reference to your `MenuFragment` in your `MainActivity`. When you create your `Fragment`, you need to tell Dagger to inject it, by calling `ObjectGraph.inject(T)`:

```
MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
this.objectGraph.inject(fragment);
Transaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// etc.
```

Dagger will now notice the `@Inject` annotation on your `MenuAdapterGenerator`, and call `provideMenuAdapterGenerator()` to inject it.

---

I'd like to recommend [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606149/android-ioc-dagger-framework-how-to-inject-a-nested-field/27623016#27623016) of mine, which discusses Constructor Injection. Although `Fragment`s are one of the few cases this is not possible (along with `Activity`s and `View`s), you might want to consider using that technique for injecting possible other custom classes.

Comment: Edited the above code to show your suggestions, yet my generator is still null :-/

Comment: Whoops, my generator was still null because I wasn't actually using that instance I created by "new". Changed my code to use it, and it's working. Excellent, thanks for your help. Though I see less of an advantage to using DI at all if you still have to do all this manual wiring. I guess the true benefits come in when you create a second flavor of your app.

Comment: Great! About your DI point, it *will* become easier when your app gets bigger. Especially if you're using Constructor Injection. The way you're using Dagger now is kind of a 'hack', because you can't (shouldn't) use constructors with arguments in `Fragment`s.

Comment: Hmm, but I'm not using any constructors with arguments on a Fragment? Also, is it common to have to pass the ObjectGraph around via constructors everywhere?

Comment: No, you're not, and that's a good thing. And it shouldn't be too common to pass it around. Dagger should be able to instantiate your whole instance tree.

Comment: Ok I think I'm 98% of the way to comprehending Dagger. My last question: how do you deal with nested Fragments? My MainApplication creates a parent Fragment. This parent Fragment has a navbar Fragment as a member. I want to inject my MainApplication into the navbar Fragment (because it contains the logic for opening my drawer menu). Can I do this without passing ObjectGraph into the parent?

Comment: Perhaps you're better off creating a new question so you can show your code structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077618/using-dagger-with-nested-fragment-and-views