# Dependency injection through constructor or attribute?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I've seen two ways to inject dependency with Unity.

**With Constructor :**

```
private readonly IDummyService _dummyService;

public AuthController(IDummyService dummyService)
{
    this._dummyService = dummyService;
}
```

**With Attribute :**

```
[Dependency]
public IDummyService _dummyService { get; set; }

public AuthController()
{
}
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? and which one is better to use?

Comment: You will find a lot of info on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503584/dependency-injection-through-constructors-or-property-setters

Comment: I don't think there are a lot of differences. I like the constructor call personally though, because you can always check if you don't get null (and not a nullrefexception elsewhere).

Comment: thanks for the link! I cannot find it earlier

Comment: Always choose constructor injection. Otherwise you're introducing a tight coupling between your code and DI container you use.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : I prefer using constructor injection. But the other forms of injection have their merit too (preventing circular dependencies for instance)

Comment: @Falanwe But that's a problem. In first place you should design your classes in such a way that it doesn't require circular dependency. If it is unavoidable, use property injection(But not using the attributes).  Using attributes couples your code with DI container; If you want to replace your container tomorrow, you're in trouble.