# Difference between @inject annotation and Constructor/Setter + XML config Injection?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi, inject

( This is not a duplicate question, There is nothing about the @inject annotation here : [Dependency injection through constructors or property setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503584/dependency-injection-through-constructors-or-property-setters) )

---

If I understand it right, in Spring for example, we define a bean in the xml file, and then we can inject it via constructor or setter, so the Spring IOC container will manage the lifecycle of that bean.

Example 1 :

```
class Test {

    private Bean bean;

    //constructor injectioon
    public Test(Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
    //setter injection
    public setBean(Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
}
```

So what is the difference between the example 1 and the following example ( and correct me please if I'm wrong about what I've said in the first paragraph :

Example 2 :

```
class Test {

    @inject
    private Bean bean;

    public Test() {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They work the same. But in Spring we should use `@Autowire` instead of `@Inject`

Comment: There are ways to inject a value, they do not have differences.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @KrzysztofMajewski - Why is that? Why unnecessarily add a dependency to Spring?

Comment: Constructor injection can fail if you have a circular dependency between two beans. That's the only difference that I've noticed, but it is more of a design issue than anything.

Comment: @DavidR You are right. They can be used interchangeable to inject Spring beans.

Comment: Autowired is just the legacy version of Inject. They are synonymous with the exception that Autowired forces a dependency on Spring.

Comment: And it supports the "required" parameter which Inject doesn't support. So if you need this parameter, you have to use Autowired.