# PHP constructor based dependency inject vs new. Which one is more efficient?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

There are two types of Dependency injection http://www.javatpoint.com/dependency-injection-in-spring

1. Constructor-based dependency injection
2. Setter-based dependency injection

However Which one of the following is more efficient and why? or are they Same?, in other words Dependency Injection vs `new`ing the object?

```
class User
{
   private $departmentRepo;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->departmentRepo = new DepartmentRepository();
   }
}

// OR

class User
{
   private $departmentRepo;

   public function __construct(DepartmentRepository $departmentRepo)
   {
     $this->departmentRepo = $departmentRepo;
   }
}
```

### EDIT

@Chetan Ameta, Federico, Sougata
[Dependency injection through constructors or property setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503584/dependency-injection-through-constructors-or-property-setters) is more about which of the Dependency method to use. The later question is about justifying which of the DI method to use (Constructor or Setter/Getter).

However my question is about DI vs new ing the object. Why do we use DI? why not Just `new` the class and use the object?
Note: In my question, example code is in PHP. Having experience PHP and JavaSpring, I don't see much difference in using DI or OOP in both the languages.